# Aggregating timeseries data on multiple axises?

Tags: database-design, time-series, mariadb, rdbms

I have many millions of time-series points coming in each day with two important axes I need to search over. My data looks like the following:

```
X, Y, value, TIMESTAMP
```

Originally these were stored in MariaDB but the table size is growing too fast. Doing simple aggregate queries (like `SUM()`) are taking too long even on a medium-sized server with indexes.

Here are some example queries:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl 
WHERE X = 23 AND Y = 46 AND TIMESTAMP > NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY

SELECT X, Y, COUNT(*) FROM tbl
WHERE TIMESTAMP > NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY
GROUP BY X, Y
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

I have two indexes:

```
X, Y, value
X, Y, TIMESTAMP
```

I'm looking for recommendations on ways (or new databases) to store this data providing fast lookups for any combination of X and Y while filtering on TIMESTAMP or value.

Comment: Well you can choose to simulate/emulate a [Materialized view](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Materialized_view) in MySQL/MariaDB .. [This](https://www.fromdual.com/mysql-materialized-views) is how you would simulate/emulate it on MySQL/MariaDB.

Comment: A materialized view requires a long-running query the same as the raw requires above. Running these on every insert, or even once-a-day is less than ideal, and eventually will be too slow as the database grows. I'm looking for less-resource intensive ways to aggregate the data. Perhaps looking at other storage systems, or a mix of a caching layer + MariaDB/MySQL would help.

Comment: Very true still waiting MariaDB/MySQL supports Materialized view natively because it is a SQL 2003 standard.. Also MariaDB supports [System-Versioned Tables](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/system-versioned-tables/) which might be optimized for quering timestamp based information?  Also can you post the `SHOW  CREATE TABLE table` statements for both tables and `EXPLAIN query` output for both queries?

Comment: .. also [Partitioning](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/partitioning-overview/) comes to mind .. Also `ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC` which is always slow because you sort on a calculated column you can't optimize this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Raymond Nijland posted a recommendation to use a materialized view (a table built from queries on other table(s)). At first I dismissed it because the query I was currently using to build the materialized view required (almost) a full table scan to run the calculation which was the issue I was trying to avoid.

However, a materialized view can also be built *one piece at a time*, which turns out to be a great solution to this problem for both NoSQL and SQL databases (provided indexes).

### RDBMS

If an insert arrived for axis `X` and `Y`, then fetch only records with the `X` and `Y` axes and re-run the calculation on them. In my case this works great because the frequency of daily inserts per axis pair is very low (though all axis pair inserts is high).

When:

```
INSERT X, Y, value, TIMESTAMP
```

Then run:

```
INSERT INTO reports (X, Y, cnt, updated_at, ...) 
SELECT X, Y, COUNT(*), NOW(), ...(other columns)... FROM tbl 
WHERE X = ? AND Y = ? AND TIMESTAMP BETWEEEN ? AND ?)
```

This is a vague example, but assuming properly structured indexes and partition/primary keys you can maintain an always-updated materialized reports table of sorts.

If there are axes which are not updated very often, you can run a second background task to identify and remove/update rows `WHERE updated_at < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY`.

### Redis

Atomic counters are a very useful way to keep an aggregate score for incoming metrics. After every insert, simply update a separate composite key counter for the axis you care about:

```
redis> SET X#Y#2020-01-01 1
"OK"
redis> INCR X#Y#2020-01-01
(integer) 2
```

This is harder for multiple axes data.

### DynamoDB, MongoDB, etc...

- AWS DynamoDB has "streams" which provide a way for a AWS Lambda function to be notified on a change.
- MongoDB has the changelog which you can use to react to database updates.

In both cases, you can run a background map/reduce on the data and update a calculation from the data you scanned.

This is often a lot more expensive of an operation than what is done with smaller data sets that fit in memory (Redis) or a RDMBS (above).

*Note: I'm still looking for better solutions to time-series data with multiple axes on NoSQL platforms as my current recommendation is easier said than done.*

Answer (score 1):

Building on your answer on using **materialized views** for your queries, there is an improvement that can be made if:

> The time series data are written "realtime" in the database

meaning that you **do not write data that passes a "window" in the past**, eg. let`s assume yesterday.

In this case, you could combine data from a materialized view, **a table holding aggregated data for each day in the past**.

The idea is that when a query is made between specific datetimes, eg startTime = 2019-03-03 12:00:00 -> endTime = 2019-04-02 12:00:00:

- Get the aggregated data from the time series table where TIMESTAMP is between startTime - till the end of the day of startTime (2019-03-03 12:00:00,2019-03-04 00:00:00)
- Get aggregated data from the materialized view for days between (2019-03-04,2019-04-01)
- Get the aggregated data from the time series table where TIMESTAMP is between startTime - till the end of the day of startTime (2019-04-02 00:00:00,2019-04-02 12:00:00)
- Finally combine the values above using **union all**.

[image]

Suppose tables `data` and `AggData`:

```
CREATE TABLE `data` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `X` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
 `Y` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
 `value` float(10,2) NOT NULL,
 `TIMESTAMP` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `AggData` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `X` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
 `Y` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
 `DAY` date NOT NULL,
 `sum1` float NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

You can combine the data using this procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `getDataForPeriods`(IN `startTime` INT(32), IN `endTime` INT(32), OUT `AggSum1` FLOAT)
    NO SQL
BEGIN
SELECT SUM(allData.summed1) INTO AggSum1
FROM (SELECT SUM(d1.value) AS summed1,d1.X AS X,d1.Y AS Y FROM `data` d1
WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(d1.`TIMESTAMP`) > startTime
AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(d1.`TIMESTAMP`) <  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(startTime + 24*60*60)))
GROUP BY d1.X,d1.Y
      UNION ALL
SELECT SUM(s1.`sum1`) AS summed1,s1.X AS X,s1.Y AS Y FROM AggData s1
WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(s1.DAY) > startTime 
AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(s1.DAY) + 24*60*60 < endTime
GROUP BY s1.X,s1.Y
     UNION ALL
     SELECT SUM(d2.value) AS summed1,d2.X AS X,d2.Y AS Y FROM `data` d2
WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(d2.`TIMESTAMP`) > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(endTime)))
AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(d2.`TIMESTAMP`) < endTime
GROUP BY d2.X,d2.Y) allData
GROUP BY allData.X,allData.Y;
END
```

Looking at the condition `WHERE TIMESTAMP > NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY`, this would be an improvement for conditions like this, as:

- No frequent updates are needed for the materialized table
- the bottleneck seems to be that the query returns a large result set for 30 days and then aggregate it, this way you return most of the data from the materialized table and aggregate far less rows

Note that when getting data close to the **present time** `NOW()` , you could **change the 3rd query to include more days**, not only today, in case you still receive time series data eg for yesterday.

Comment: Less frequent updates for the materialized table is a neat idea. However, depending on the daily volume may not be an option for all. You didn't address actually maintaining/updating the materialized table, but I talked about ways to incrementally build one in my answer that should work for even larger datasets.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL and MariaDB do not have the specifics needed, but Summary tables are the way to go.  But first...

```
mysql> SELECT NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY;
+-------------------------+
| NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY |
+-------------------------+
| 2019-03-10 11:48:24     |
+-------------------------+
```

Do you really want to span a 30-day period starting at some *second*?  Typically, people want just 30 full days:

```
WHERE ts >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY
  AND ts  < CURDATE();

mysql> SELECT CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY, CURDATE();
+-----------------------------+------------+
| CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY | CURDATE()  |
+-----------------------------+------------+
| 2019-03-10                  | 2019-04-09 |
+-----------------------------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

or even honor variable-length months:

```
WHERE ts >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
  AND ts  < CURDATE();

mysql> SELECT CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH, CURDATE();
+------------------------------+------------+
| CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH | CURDATE()  |
+------------------------------+------------+
| 2019-03-09                   | 2019-04-09 |
+------------------------------+------------+
```

If you are willing to look only at whole days, building and maintaining a Summary table (a la materialized view) is easy and very efficient:

```
CREATE TABLE SummaryXY (
    x ...,
    y ...,
    dy DATE,
    ct INT UNSIGNED,
    PRIMARY KEY(x,y,dy)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

You would have a job to add new rows just after midnight every hight.

If, on the other hand, you need to go up-to-the-current-second, the updating can be via IODKU (`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE...`), which will take care of updating or inserting, as needed.

If you need to go back to hours instead of days, change `dy`.  But if you really need to go back to an arbitrary second, then do the task in 2 steps:

```
SELECT
    ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM RawData WHERE ... (the partial day 30 days ago) ) +
    ( SELECT SUM(ct) FROM SummaryXY WHERE ... (the 30 full days) );
```

(And deal with the partial current day either by IODKU or a similar `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM RawDATA`.)

Was your simple example as complex as you need?  What I describe will work well for `X=constant AND y=constant AND ts...`,  but not for `X>constant` etc.

If you need `AVG(value)`, then store `COUNT(*)` (as above) and `SUM(VALUE)`.  Then this gives you the average:

```
SUM(value_sum) / SUM(ct)
```

If you also need `WHERE x=1 AND w=2 AND ts...`, then build a second Summary table based on `x,w,ts`.

If you also need `WHERE x=1 AND y=1 AND z=3 AND ts...`, then build a Summary table based on `x,y,z,ts`, but make use of it for `x,y,ts`.  Perhaps typical is 5 summary tables handling 40 cases.

More discussion of summary tables:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables

Your second query (`GROUP BY X, Y  ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC`) currently does a table scan of the big Raw table, even if you index `ts`.  With my suggested summary table, the query would be a table can of the summary table.  Since this might 10 times as small, a table scan of it will be significantly faster.

The extra sort on `COUNT(*)` it a minor burden; that depends on the number of rows in the result set.

Comment: I'm currently using a summary table actually. However, generating it daily is painful and the concept requires some additional forethought to spread the load. The same is true if using a NoSQL store (see my answer below).

Comment: @Xeoncross - Provide more details; I may have further tips.  (Start a new question with more specifics.)  A quick guess:  Update the summary table every hour instead of every day.  Also, see the tips in my link.